# django sanction: TypeError: create_superuser() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to integrate the [django-sanction](https://github.com/demianbrecht/django-sanction) library on my small blog (I am a django beginner), but, when I set up the [example](https://github.com/demianbrecht/django-sanction/tree/master/example) as in the package, and then run syncdb, I get:

```
TypeError: create_superuser() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

I guess the problem is with the [user model](https://github.com/demianbrecht/django-sanction/blob/master/example/core/models.py) defined in the package, but I am unsure how to get rid of this error.

I have tried adding an email field (since I think create_superuser() requires an email field to be passed), as follows:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email_address']
    ....
```

but this does not solve the error. I guess I probably explicitly need to pass the email field to the create_superuser() method (?). Any help as to how to solve this error would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OK - It turned out that the author had not updated his repo - Now super user is created without any problems.

Comment: What exactly was the issue? What did the author update that fixed it?

Comment: this is very unhelpful